# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to '...Tasks<int>'

Tags: c#, task

if this is async, it'll return with no error, why is it throwing an error without being async, async is worthless in this operation.

```
public Task<int> countUp()
{
    string compare = txtTag.Text;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (compare == dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString())
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                count++;
                txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
            }));
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to return a `Task<int>` rather than just a normal `int`?

Comment: i need it to run on another thread.  How do you pass in instructions from the UI to a task?

Comment: You seem to be under the mistaken impression that an async method runs on another thread. It does not. An async method contains an *asynchronous await*, and *returns immediately when the await happens*. It then *resumes where it left off* when the awaited value is available. Make sure you understand that; it is **absolutely not the case** that an async method necessarily runs on another thread; in fact, one of the reasons we added async methods to C# was to *decrease* the reliance on threads as an asynchrony mechanism.

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears to be both reading and writing fields of controls; if that's the case, this method may only be run on the UI thread. Frankly this code looks very suspicious. What I would do if I were you is *start a new question*, describe carefully what you are trying to do, and ask for help making that happen.

Answer (score 35):

Well, you *could* return a completed Task:

```
return Task.FromResult(count);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx

Why you'd want to return a Task is a bit of a mystery though. Conceptually, a Task represents a promise that something will happen at some time in the future. In your case, it's already happened, so using a Task is completely pointless.

Answer (score 10):

As the error clearly states, you can't return an `int` as a `Task<int>`.  (unless you make it an `async` method, which does compile-time magic to create a `Task<T>`.

If your method isn't asynchronous, you shouldn't be returning a `Task<T>` in the first place.
Instead, just return `int` directly.

If, for some reason, you *need* to return a `Task<T>`, you can call `Task.FromResult()` to create a finished task with a given value.

Answer (score 4):

The code here is obviously incorrect. Try to look at the return type in your code. You are returning and `int` which mismatch the return type that expecting a `Task<int>`. If you are not going to use async await in this method, you can just change your return type to `int`.

However, if you insist on returning `Task<int>` instead of `int`, you can use the following for your return statement

```
return Task.FromResult(count)
```

This will wrap your `int` into `Task<int>`. For more information of `Task.FromResult`, you can visit :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx
[What is the use for Task.FromResult<TResult> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568280/what-is-the-use-for-task-fromresulttresult-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in this method indicating that it is an asynchronous method, except for the fact that you've declared it to return `Task<int>`.

However, you're not returning a `Task<int>`, you're returning `count`, an `int`.

Since you're not waiting for the action to complete, I would remove the `Task<int>` return type and replace it with just `int` instead as this method is completely synchronous (except for the part you're not waiting for anyway).