# What is the use for Task.FromResult<TResult> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

In C# and TPL ([Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)), the `Task` class represents an ongoing work that produces a value of type T.

I'd like to know what is the need for the [Task.FromResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx) method ?

That is: In a scenario where you already have the produced value at hand, what is the need to wrap it back into a Task?

The only thing that comes to mind is that it's used as some adapter for other methods accepting a Task instance.

Comment: is this helps you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607.aspx

Comment: To some extent I agree with that, but the creation of dense, useful, consolidated, discsussion-oriented pages like this is a huge benefit. I almost always learn more from a good, dense stackoverflow page than from googling and doing research across multiple places, so in this case, I'm really glad he posted this.

Comment: I think Google brings me to SO and SO ask me to go to Google. It is a circular reference :)

Comment: I really hate it if somebody deletes a comment that already had answers. Leads to waste of brain capacity when trying to understand...

Answer (score 359, accepted):

There are two common use cases I've found:

1. When you're implementing an interface that allows asynchronous callers, but your implementation is synchronous.
2. When you're stubbing/mocking asynchronous code for testing.

Comment: A good case for #1 is a web service.  You could have a synchronous service method that returns `Task.FromResult` and a client that awaits asynchronously for the network I/O.  This way you can share the same interface between client/server using `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: For instance the ChallengeAsync method. WTF were the designers at MS thinking? There is absolutely no reason for this method to return a Task. And all the sample code from MS simply has FromResult(0). Hopefully the compiler is smart enough to optimize this away, and doesn't actually spawn a new thread and then kill it right away!

Comment: @JohnHenckel: OWIN is designed from the ground up to be async-friendly. Interfaces and base classes often use async signatures because it just *allows* (not *forces*) the implementation to be async. So it's similar to `IEnumerable<T>` deriving from `IDisposable` - it *allows* the enumerable to have disposable resources, not *forces* it to. Neither `FromResult`, `async`, nor `await` will spawn threads.

Comment: @StephenCleary hmhm, thanks for explaining that. I had assumed that await would spawn, but I tried it and I see it doesn't. Only Task.Run does. Therefore, x = await Task.FromResult(0); is equivalent to saying x = 0; that's confusing, but good to know!

Comment: @JohnHenckel I think the first thing await does is check the status of IsCompleted, and if it is true, it continues down the same thread synchronously.  Task.FromResult( ) creates a task that has the IsCompleted already set to true for the purpose of optimization.

Comment: 1 - but why would you do this? In awaitable method you still can call both sync and async methods? Can you explain? From.Result will allow to call it as async, but in reality it will run synchronously and will block the thread. So it will simply mislead the caller

Comment: @OlegI: For I/O operations, the *best* solution is to implement it asynchronously, but sometimes you don't have that choice. Also, sometimes you *can* implement it synchronously (e.g., a cached result, falling back to an asynchronous implementation if the value isn't cached). More generally, a `Task`-returning method means "*may* be asynchronous". So sometimes methods are given an asynchronous signature knowing full well that some implementations will be synchronous (e.g., `NetworkStream` should be async, but `MemoryStream` should be sync).

Comment: @StephenCleary understand. Also, I think, when you create abstraction you want it to be awaitable, even though if a concrete implementation of that abstraction doesn't run anything asynchronous YET, but probably when you will change concrete abstraction implementation it WILL call something awaitable. So declaring abstraction with Task as return type will make your concrete implementation flexible enough to run both sync and async operations without changing abstraction signature. I feel like this is one of the main purposes of Task.FromResult if I am correct...

Comment: @OlegI: Yes. This is one use case for `Task.FromResult`; another is for unit testing (stub implementations of asynchronous interfaces).

Comment: `Task.FromResult` is not for this type of use, it's recomended to use with an async operation, i.e.: when your async method caches something, on calling this method and the cache meeets your needs, you can use `Task.FromResult`, that means you is returning something from "Result" of an previously async operation.

Comment: @StephenCleary Your answers are like proofs of some mathematical theorems. When someone asks that you please exemplify the proof, nobody has to do it. It is not compulsory. That's because proof is proof. That is, your answers are not for those learning new things. You could be a knowledgable academician, but not a good teacher/lecturer. If you'd like to get advice from an ordinary coder, ALWAYS exemplify, please, with working coding examples.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire: I disagree. I've been answering programming questions for >25 years now. IMO, just providing code solutions is a disservice; far too often, the op learns nothing, copy/pastes the answer, and goes on to ask the next step in their work. I try to give guiding answers in a way that encourages the reader to learn *on their own*, thus much more effectively learning than just copying code.
That said, I *do* often give code examples, particularly if the implementation is tricky. I just didn't for this answer.

Comment: @StephenCleary _the op learns nothing, copy/pastes the answer_ When you close your eyes, the fact that you cannot see doesn't mean the world doesn't exist. That's said, if some people do that, does it mean everybody does that? I disagree at all.

Answer (score 65):

One example would be a method that makes use of a cache.  If the result is already computed, you can return a completed task with the value (using `Task.FromResult`).  If it is not, then you go ahead and return a task representing ongoing work.

Cache Example: [Cache Example using Task.FromResult for Pre-computed values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks)

Comment: And completed tasks, such as the ones returned from `Task.FromResult`, can be cached.

Comment: @Paulo: keeping the entire Task object in memory seems far more wasteful than caching just the result.

Comment: Expect "value tasks" are already cached. I don't recall exactly which ones, but I think `Task.FromResult(0)`, `Task.FromResult(1)`, `Task.FromResult(false)` and `Task.FromResult(true)` are cached. You're not supposed to cache a task for a network access but one from result is perfectly fine. Would you prefer to create one each time you need to return the value?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I don't think you've responded to Ben's point. What is the benefit to caching the *Task* rather than simply caching the *TResult* that the task returned?

Comment: ... and to answer my own question, the benefit of a cache of *Tasks* is that some of them can be completed tasks, and others can be ones that have not yet finished. Callers don't have to care: they do an asynchronous call, and if it is already completed, they get an answer immediately when they await, if not, they get it later. Without these cached tasks, would either (a) require two different mechanisms, one sync and one async - cumbersome for caller, or (b) have to dynamically create a Task, every time a caller asks for an answer that is already available (if we had only cached a TResult).

Comment: I get it now.  The wording of the answer was slightly confusing.  The Task itself doesn't have a built in "caching" mechanism.  But if you wrote a caching mechanism for ... say .... downloading files, Task<File> GetFileAync( ), you could instantly return a file that is already in cache by using Task.FromResult(cachedFile), and the await would run synchronously, saving time by not having the thread switch.

Answer (score 48):

Use it when you want to create an awaitable method without using the async keyword.
I found this example:

```
public class TextResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    string _value;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public TextResult(string value, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _value = value;
        _request = request;
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(_value),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Here you are creating your own implementation of the IHttpActionResult interface to be used in a Web Api Action. The ExecuteAsync method is expected to be asynchronous but you don't have to use the async keyword to make it asynchronous and awaitable.  Since you already have the result and don't need to await anything it's better to use Task.FromResult.

Answer (score 27):

From msft.com [Create pre-computed tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks) with `Task.FromResult`:

> This method is useful when you perform an asynchronous operation that returns a Task object, and the result of that Task object is already computed.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Task.FromResult()` when you want to have a asynchronous operation but sometimes the result is in hand synchronously. You can find a good sample here: [Create pre-computed tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks).

Comment: in your good sample, the result is not in hand synchronously, the operation is all async, the `Task.FromResult` is used to get a previously cached async result.

Answer (score -2):

I would argue that you could use Task.FromResult for methods that are synchronous that take a long time to complete while you can do other independent work in your code. Id rather make those methods to call async though. But imagine the situation where you have no control over the code called and you want that implicit parallel processing.

Comment: Not sure why SO sorting puts this answer at the top of the list, but it is incorrect. There is no implicit parallel processing by calling `await Task.FromResult(...)` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769625/does-await-task-completedtask-mean-the-async-method-will-run-synchronously) for an explanation).

Rather it runs synchronously. If you wish to convert a long-running synchronous method such that it can be called in parallel with another, you should use `await Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());` instead.

Comment: @nicholas What do you mean by "convert"? You can't use "await" in synchronous methods. Do you mean your "LongRunningTask" is the synchronous method?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan - funny, re-reading this comment now I am not sure what I was thinking. I believe by convert I meant "pretend the a long-running blocking call is asynchronous". In hindsight, there are caveats to my comment which are worth mentioning. Running a blocking operation within a `Task.Run(...)` call will usually push the long operation to a thread pool thread. If this is an ASP.NET Core handler, you are already on the thread pool, so this has no effect besides an unnecessary context switch. Also, this pattern can lead to thread pool starvation if misused. tl;dr dont do this.

Answer (score -2):

Task.Run() creates an lambda thread, no async is required and returns a type object. In my example, I have multiple tasks running simulatenously awaiting their completion.   Once all the tasks have completed, I can cycle through their results.  Task.FromResult is used to push a task result not generated by Task.Run()

The Task.FromResult pushs a type object in this case RecordStruct class in Result class.  I created to tasks calling the function getData.  The Task.WaitAll processes each of the task and push the results into an array of result object of type RecordStruct.   I then access the attribute element of the RecordStruct Class as a result

```
    public class RecordStruct
    {
        public RecordStruct(string _element) {
            element = _element;
        }
        public string element { get;set; }
    }

public class TaskCustom
    {
        public Task<RecordStruct> getData(string phrase)
        {
            if (phrase == "hello boise")
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new RecordStruct("Boise is a great place to live"));
            }

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return new RecordStruct(phrase);
            });
        }
    } 

[Fact]
        public async Task TestFactory()
        {
            TaskCustom obj = new TaskCustom();
            List<Task<RecordStruct>> tasks = new List<Task<RecordStruct>>();
            tasks.Add(obj.getData("hello world"));
            tasks.Add(obj.getData("hello boise"));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            for(int ctr = 0; ctr < tasks.Count; ctr++) {
                if (tasks[ctr].Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                    output.WriteLine(" Task fault occurred");
                else
                {
                    output.WriteLine("test sent {0}",
                                      tasks[ctr].Result.element);
                    Assert.True(true);
                }
            }
        }
```