# How to return on Task<int>?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I've this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // start import process
    Task<int> task = StartImportProcess();
    task.Wait();
    // check result

    // process finished
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task<int> StartImportProcess()
{
    int result = 0;
    result = await ImportCustomers();

    // some other async/await operations

    return result;
}

static Task<int> ImportCustomers()
{
    // some heavy operations

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    return 1; // <<< what should I return?
}
```

Using `Task` and `async/await`. I'd like to return an `int` as result of the task. Which object whould I return? `return 1;` won't work.

Comment: `return Task.FromResult(1)` More about [`Task.FromResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568280/what-is-the-use-for-task-fromresulttresult-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 23):

You should use `Task.FromResult`, (and don't use `Thread.Sleep` from a `Task`):

```
static async Task<int> ImportCustomers()
{
    // some heavy operations

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    // Already awaited, so we can return the result as-is.
    return 1;

    // Or: if not already awaited anything,
    //     and also with non-async tasks, use:
    return Task.FromResult(1);
}
```

Comment: Uhm. But how would Task.Delay(1000) be implemented so? Somethings like         `public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(millisecondsDelay);

            return Task.FromResult(1);
        }` I believe?

Comment: Where did you get that nonsense from? The implementation is entirely different: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5863.

Comment: "Nothing awaited: does the method need to be async?" - No, the OP's method wasn't `async`.

Comment: The fact is: I need to do heavy operation within that function. Not using await inside anymore. If you see its not async that method. How would I do it?

Comment: @Enigmativity Since `Thread.Sleep` might lock the main thread, I thought using `Task.Delay` with an `await` was a better option. Since it is unclear what OP wants to do, I thought I would give both options.

Comment: @markzzz Then return `Task.FromResult(1)` as suggested in my answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - My thought was that the OP put in `Thread.Sleep(1000);` just to simulate heavy work.

Comment: Mine too, but what if he has an `async` method to call, just like `Task.Delay`, then there would be no need for `Task.FromResult`. @Enigmativity